# Enviar localização do gps para um servidor

Tags: java, android, rest

Eu tenho um service para pegar a localização do usuário, porém estou precisando passar a latitude e longitude via request para um servidor, porém eu tentei fazer essa request dentro do método `onLocationChanged()` usando OkHttpClient, mas sem sucesso.

Alguém tem alguma outra dica do que eu posso fazer nessa situação?

```
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                    Context contexto = getApplicationContext();
                    int duracao = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;com

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(contexto, "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(), duracao);
                    toast.show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                }


            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é recomendado fazer a request dentro do método `onLocationChanged()` porque ele é chamado pela thread principal, que controla a interface com o usuário. Portanto se fizer aí vai causar travamentos (a aplicação vai deixar de responder enquanto a request está sendo feita).

O que pode ser feito nesse ponto da aplicação é criar um thread separado para executar a request.

Comment: como é um service, eu faço a thread no proprio service??

Comment: Não sabia que era um Service. Talvez seja melhor passar a latitude e longitude para um segundo Service responsável por fazer a request.

Comment: Essa é nova pra mim, Se eu consigo passar informações de um service pra outro, eu faço isso dentro de um próprio service? To tentando dar uma pesquisa, mas se tu tiver algum conteúdo interessante para eu buscar, seria de deveras ajuda

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29192767/2241463

Comment: E se por obséquio, eu quisesse que a localização fosse passada para esse segundo service de X em X tempo?

Comment: Aí teria que ver o recurso de agendamento de tarefas do Android. Não lembro porque estou enferrujado